# ul#topnav background issue

Tags: html, css

I have made a navigation horizontal bar, but I seem to have a following issue with it and not sure what exactly could be causing it. I want the background to extend until the edge of the list.

[image]

HTML code...

```
<li><a href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<?php
if(!Auth::LoggedIn())
{
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/login'); ?>">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/registration'); ?>">Register</a></li>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/profile'); ?>">Pilot Center</a></li>

<?php
}
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo url('/acars') ?>">Live Map</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Airline</a>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/about'); ?>">About&nbsp;Us</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/history'); ?>">History&nbsp;&&nbsp;Milestones</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/staff'); ?>">Staff</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pilots'); ?>">Pilot&nbsp;Roster</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/managementopportunities'); ?>">Management&nbsp;Careers</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/stepone'); ?>">Pilot&nbsp;Careers</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Operations</a>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/fleet'); ?>">Fleet</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/hubs'); ?>">Hubs</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/FrontSchedules'); ?>">Schedules</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Community</a>
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo url('/contact'); ?>">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is the CSS code I have.

```
ul#topnav {
list-style-type: none;
background-image: url(../images/navi_bg.png);
height: 30px;
width: 1020px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:0px;
border:2px solid #FF9;
}

ul#topnav li {
float: left;
}

ul#topnav a {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:right;
padding-right: 14px;
padding-left: 14px;
display: block;
line-height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 13px;
color:#FF9;
}

ul#topnav a:hover {
color: #FFF;
background-image: url(../images/hover_bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}

ul#nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: auto;
line-height:normal;
}

ul li {
position: relative;
}

li ul {
position: absolute;
left: 149;
top: 30;
background: #003663;
display: none;
z-index: 1;
}

ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover ul, li.over ul { 
display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was just actually checking it, edited the post.

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 you did not include the css for your subnav.

Comment: Edited again, sorry, haven't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're floating left your submenu list items as well, which is causing your background image to wrap around your list element instead of displaying as a block item. Modify the following rule to target only the children list items of your main nav `ul`:

**Change this**

```
ul#topnav li {
    float: left;
}
```

**Into this**

```
ul#topnav > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Smashing, thank you. I wouldn't know that > is possible to use in CSS, nice to know.

Comment: @HighFlyerPL185 its called the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) and its used to target the children of an element only, in this case it was used to target your first level list items and not your submenu items.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>

<li>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/managementopportunities'); ?>">Management&nbsp;Careers</a></li> 
        <li><a href="<?php echo url('/pages/stepone'); ?>">Pilot&nbsp;Careers</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

You're not wrapping you `<ul id="nav">` in a list element `<li>`, also you have multiple elements in your html with the id="nav" id can only be used to uniquely identify a single element. You need to change these to classes, it will give you a clearer picture of what's wrong